# CakePHP: Using LOCATE clause in $this->Model->find

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

The following query returns results based on the system assigned to the user. All of the user's system assignments are stored in a comma-delimited array in a column called `systems`. (So, `22,50,8,18`, for example).

```
SELECT full_name, email_address FROM users WHERE dept_id = 1 AND LOCATE('8', systems);
```

When this query is run in MySQL, it returns the name and e-mail address of every user who has system 8 assigned to them. I need to format this query for CakePHP 2.0 and the LOCATE parameter will come from a variable in my add.ctp file (`$current['Doc']['dept_id']`). So far, I've got this, which works fine for finding everyone with `dept_id = 1`:

```
$toarray = $this->User->find('all', array(
             'fields' => array('User.email_address', 'User.full_name'),
             'conditions' => array('User.dept_id' => 1)
              )
           );
```

I'm not at all clear on how to incorporate a LOCATE clause into this structure so that I only get the users who have the system selected in add.ctp assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried what would be the assumed answer?

```
$toarray = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('User.email_address', 'User.full_name'),
    'conditions' => array('User.dept_id' => 1, "LOCATE('8', systems)")
));
```

Comment: The formatting of this piece: `"LOCATE('8', systems)"` was what I was having trouble with. Thank you for your help.